# po:menu with ID

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a problem in the menu component of primefaces olympos that I did not allow changing the ID to refer to in a link.

layoutmenu.xhtml page

xmlns:po"http://primefaces.org/olympos"

```
<po:menu class="active" id="layout-main" model = "#{menuMB.principalModel}" />
<po:menu id="personal layout" model = "#{menuMB.pessoalModel}" />
```

When I try to reference a link, it does not find these IDs (layout-main, layout-personal), as both menus are the same ID with the name "layout-menu"

layouttabmenu.xhtml page

```
<a id="menu-principal" href="#" rel="layout-principal" />
<a id="menu-pessoal" href="#" rel="layout-pessoal" />

<ui: include src="layoutmenu.xhtml" />
```

Does anyone know a solution for setting the ID?

Comment: Uhhhhh a space between the # and { makes it something else than an EL.... and a space between po: and menu??? And spaces around the =  Please correct those.

Comment: That is a custom component of the Primefaces Premium Theme.  You should ask PrimeTek on their forum here: https://forum.primefaces.org/viewforum.php?f=91